# Creating a function using PL/SQL

Tags: database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have the following table:

```
create table movie(
    movie_id integer primary key,
    title varchar(500) not null,
    kind varchar(30),
    year integer not null
);
```

I want to create a function:

```
addMovie(title, kind, year)
```

The function must insert a new row into the movie table with a unique movie_id, and then return the movie_id.

This is the first time I'm using PL/SQL, so I'm kind of lost at the moment - couldn't find any (good) examples so far.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not.... anymore :-)

Comment: Wrong. @LalitKumarB can you expand on that please? Why is a function not meant for DML?

Comment: Ok, so why would you execute an operation to create data (addMovie) as part of a SQL statement? I don't think you would. Instead you would execute addMovie as a discrete call in PL/SQL and you may quite sensibly want to return the unique ID generated by this operation, in which case, use of a function is perfectly adequate.

Comment: You provided a solution, but you also provided a bit of nonsense to go with it. Your suggestion that addMovie may be used as part of a SQL statement and that this would therefore make a Function unsuitable is poor judgement.

Comment: Just my 2c: I agree with Lalit that this should be a procedure, not a function, but disagree with the rationale. `addMovie` changes the database state, so it should be a procedure (possibly with an OUT parameter). Functions with non-trivial side effects (e.g. inserting data) are (generally) poor programming practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function needs to do 3 things

- Generate the unique movie id
- Insert into the table
- Return the generated id

Let's take it one step at a time

#### Generate the unique movie id

The best way to do it is to use a seqeuence which will generated a id for you. Look up on [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314)

#### Insert into the table

This is done by a straightforward insert. Since the movie id is generated by the sequence, we use `sequence_name.nextval` in the insert statement. Thus the insert statement looks like

```
INSERT INTO movie(movie_id, title, kind, year) values (movie_id_seq.nextval, title, kind, year)
```

#### Return the generated id back

You can make use of the [Returning clause in a DML](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/returninginto_clause.htm) to return the generated id back into a variable. And then use the RETURN statement to return the value back.

So this is how your function will look like

```
FUNCTION addmovie(p_title,
                  p_kind,
                  p_year)
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_id movie.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO movie
              (
                          movie_id,
                          title,
                          kind,
                          year
              )
              VALUES
              (
                          movie_id_seq.NEXTVAL,
                          p_title,
                          p_kind,
                          p_year
              )
  returning   id
  INTO        v_id;

  RETURN v_id;
END;
```

Note that this is a fairly basic function, with no error checking, exception handling - I'll leave it up to you.

---

Note that max(movie_id)+1 isn't the best way forward, for purposes of the assignment. You'll need

```
SELECT max(movie_id)+1 into v_id from movies;
```

before the insert statement.

Also, because of the DML, you can't use this function as part of a query.

Comment: I'm aware that a sequence would probably be the best way to generate a unique id. However this is not possible as far as this assignment goes.
The idea is to use something like max(movie.movie_id)+1.

Comment: Or an **IDENTITY column** if you are on `12c` version. See my answer. Sequence and trigger was prior 12c approach.